# PHP - Combine object with $this

Tags: php, object, cakephp

Is it possible to combine one object with $this object?
I'm using CakePHP framework and I'm having my own classes to handle some stuff. I'm passing $this from controller to my class:

```
$event = new EventObject($this);
```

So I can do stuff like in my class:

```
$this -> Cake -> loadModel('Events');
```

I want to be able to do the following in my class:

```
$this -> loadModel('Events');
```

So I tried doing this:

```
function __construct($CakePHP) {
    $this = $CakePHP;
}
```

And:

```
function __construct($CakePHP) {
    $this = (object) array_merge((array) $this, (array) $CakePHP);
}
```

but was unable to achieve the desired result. Is it even possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thing you don't understand how a framework should be used u_u (or Your explication are really not clear)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: I want $this in scope of my class to include CakePHP object (functions) as well as it's own. So $this -> loadModel('Events') would work in scope of my class.